# gradle build suddenly doesnt work

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have been using a java backend and its has been work fine until yesterday when me and another person both started getting this error message:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve org.springframework:spring-beans:[2.5.2,3).
>     Required by:
>         project : > com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:1.18
>   Failed to list versions for org.springframework:spring-beans.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not HEAD 'http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Read timed out

I am kind of familiar with gradle but only in relation to android not java/spring and haven't encountered this type of error before.

Comment: It seems that spring-beans:2.5.2 is not present in the repository that you are referring: https://nexus.pentaho.org/#nexus-search;quick~spring-beans

Answer (score 0):

Well the resources are available when hitting the URLs with a browser. So there must be something between the machines running the build and that repository that is not working. The most likely explanation is a corporate firewall blocking traffic.

Nothing Gradle can do about that.